Stripe Webhook timeout on localhost with FastAPI
I have an issue with a stripe webhook, which I am running locally for the test.
async def my_webhook_view(request: Request, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    payload = await request.body()
    sig_header = request.headers.get('stripe-signature')
    event = None
    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
            payload, sig_header, ENDPOINT_SECRET
        )
    except ValueError as e:
        # Invalid payload
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid payload")
    except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
        # Invalid signature
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid signature")

    if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':
        #email = event['data']['object']['customer_details']['email']
        # Check if the event has already been processed
        event_id = event['id']
        if db.query(ProcessedEvent).filter_by(id=event_id).first():
            return {"message": "Event already processed"}

        # Process the event
        session = event['data']['object']
        db_event = ProcessedEvent(id=event_id)
        db.add(db_event)
        db.commit()
        msg = fulfill_checkout(event['data']['object']['id'])
        if msg == "Event received":
            print("Event received")
            return JSONResponse(status_code=200, content={"message": "Success"})
        else:
            print("Event unprocessed")
            return JSONResponse(status_code=200, content={"message": "Cancel"})

There is no delay (1s), the event is immediately received, and the debugger enters well into return JSONResponse(status_code=200, content={"message": "Success"})
but nothing happens on the stripe payment page.
I get a timeout after some time with the success url but everything has been correctly processed in the background tasks.
The checkout properly sets the success and cancel urls.
#Stripe Payment
@app.post('/create-checkout-session')
async def create_checkout_session(price_id: str = Form(...)):
    try:
        checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            line_items=[
                {
                    # Provide the exact Price ID (for example, pr_1234) of the product you want to sell
                    'price': price_id,
                    'quantity': 1,
                },
            ],
            mode='payment',
            success_url= f'{DOMAIN}/success',
            cancel_url= f'{DOMAIN}/cancel',
            billing_address_collection = 'required'
        )
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=str(e))
    
    return RedirectResponse(checkout_session.url,303)

I am providing additional details
My webhook is running locally and is listening for checkout.session.completed events only
stripe listen --events checkout.session.completed --forward-to
localhost:8000/webhook
On the stripe dashboard page, my local webhook is properly configured.
I noticed the following when I did a payment with a test card.
The "Events" tab for today ( 1st August )

In the logs, I can see the following

The checkout.session in the logs indicate a payment_status of "unpaid"

But my local webhook which received the stripe checkout.session has a status of "paid"

To summarise, Stripe is somewhat having 2 different payment statuses, paid in the Events, and unpaid in the Logs, for the same session

My understanding is that you're not redirected from the Checkout payment page to your success_url on successful payment. Is that right? If so, my recommendation would be to write in to Stripe support directly as this sounds unrelated to your code.

@Chris Thank you for the advice. I have added additional information.
